# My computer does not recognize API / CDN websites whilst being connected trough shared WiFi / Ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, ics

So I use a computer which does not have a WiFi card inside of it, but I use my laptop to share the WiFi with ethernet (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/want-to-share-wifi-connection-over-ethernet-cable/6f6d31b0-cbbd-4db7-ba06-c803d654f020) and some API / CDN sites get blocked even when the firewall is disabled and my hosts file is empty. On my laptop they work perfectly fine but not on the computer, I've even tried cloudflares DNS but when I use programs I always get errors such as "Could not retrieve api.github.com"